# Google closure compiler process node_modules

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm trying the Google Closure Compiler as an alternative to webpack. Currently I'm using the following to compile all files inside my frontend folder:

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar --process_common_js_modules --js_output_file=static/out.js 'lib/js/src/frontend/*.js'"
```

The problem is one of those files requires React & ReactDOM.
I get the following error:

```
lib/js/src/frontend/app.js:7: ERROR - Failed to load module "react"
var React    = require("react");
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

lib/js/src/frontend/app.js:8: ERROR - Failed to load module "react-dom"
var ReactDom = require("react-dom");
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How do I make sure that the Google Closure Compiler looks inside the node_modules folder to find the relevant third-party modules?

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of Closure-Compiler support node modules.

The compiler will not discover source files - you have to pass the source for each module to the compiler. In addition, you need to pass any `package.json` files from the packages to the compiler as well using `--js node_modules/react/package.json`.

If you are using modules throughout your project, you probably want to use the [dependency management flags](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Managing-Dependencies) so that the compiler automatically sorts your source files for you.

Based on your example above, your compilation command might look like this:

```
java -jar closure-compiler.jar --process_common_js_modules
    --dependency_mode=STRICT
    --module_resolution=NODE
    --entry_point="lib/js/src/frontend/app"
    --js_output_file=static/out.js
    --js='node_modules/react/package.json'
    --js='node_modules/react/**/*.js'
    --js='node_modules/react-dom/package.json'
    --js='node_modules/react-dom/**/*.js'
    --js='lib/js/src/frontend/*.js'
```

Full documentation and some additional tooling to utilize these features will be available shortly after the next release.

Comment: I tried this, but got `node_modules/assert/package.json:2: ERROR - Parse error. Semi-colon expected` Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT Built on: 2017-04-25 17:19

Comment: You now also need to add the `--module_resolution` flag. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Do you know why `package.json` files must be provided? (Just curious)